# How to remove wajam?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, adware

I have already

- deinstalled all suspicious software
- run adwcleaner
- run malwarebytes anti-malware
- deleted all cookies

still, google chrome is infected

Comment: [Remove Search.Wajam.com redirect (Virus Removal Guide)](http://malwaretips.com/blogs/search-wajam-virus/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset your google chrome...goto settings >> click on "+ Show advanced settings" at the bottom of the window >> again scorll to the bottom of the page and click on "Reset Settings"...

That's it..you made it!!!!

Answer (score -1):

[Remove](http://www.pccaretips.com/blog/how-to-get-rid-of-wajam-ads-from-browsers.html) it via the registry though it is not an easy thing. But since you have tried many ways already, you can have a try. To edit the registry, you should have skilled computer manipulation. Firstly, open the registry window by enter "regedit" in the run box and hit Enter. Secondly, click Find... optionfrom the menu. Lastly, type "wajam in the search box and look for its malicious items remove all of them. After that, do "Reset your google chrome...goto settings >> click on "+ Show advanced settings" at the bottom of the window >> again scorll to the bottom of the page and click on "Reset Settings"" Hope this helps you!

Comment: Why are you copying the accepted answer (complete with spelling mistakes)?